# Merging Data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a survey created in Google Docs used in several classes. Each class has its data in a separate Google spreadsheet. Now I want to collate all the data into a single spreadsheet. If I simply copy and paste the data into one spreadsheet, it is not recognized. How can I compile that data from the separate spreadsheets without having to re-enter it all manually?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not recognized"? Did get an error or the filters/charts/reports doesn't include the pasted data?

Answer (score 2):

1. Bring all info, using sheets, into one spreadsheet. This makes it much easier to handle.
2. Use one last sheet to bring all relevant info together.

Otherwise you need to use Google Apps Script or Import functions.....

By classes, you mean school classes I recon?

Comment: One sheet to rule them all?...Sorry, couldn't resist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the documentation on reading and writing information through Scripts?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/storing_data_spreadsheets

There's also a StackOverflow thread about how to write to multiple sheets, I think you can use the same approach to read from multiple and write to 1:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642495/google-spreadsheet-script-write-data-to-multiple-spreadsheets-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Working with scripts, apps could be one way, how about checking out this one. [CollateBox](http://www.collatebox.com/web/online-data-sharing.html) can bbe an ideal solution. I am sure u'll be  amazed with its data collation ability. For more read http://blog.collatebox.com/blog/2012/01/are-you-using-google-docs-to-share-and-collaborate-your-data-online.html

Athar

Evangelist @ CollateBox

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with the service in your answer, otherwise it will be considered spam and treated accordingly. Thanks!